# How to manage Linux file permissions in Java?

Tags: java, linux, permissions, chmod, ext3

Is there any mechanism to get and set the file/directory permissions?

For example, I want to show the permisssions of a file in a shell way:

```
-rwxr-xr--
```

Is it possible to do this using Java?

- I know that there are some methods in the `File` class to know if the file `canExecute`, `canRead` and `canWrite`, but AFAIK this info is for the current user only. I need to know the whole octal number, for example 755, so I need to get it from the user, from group and from others.
- I know that Java7 brings Posix operations, but how could do this using a smaller JRE?
- I would like not to use a command like `ls`, or `chmod`.

Comment: Can you use third party libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use external libraries, there are several:

- [JPosix](http://www.kanga.org/jposix/)
- [Posix for java](http://bmsi.com/java/posix/)
- [jnr-posix](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-posix)

If an entire library seems a hassle, creating a JNI wrapper that calls the `lstat` C function and returns the access mode takes you about 10 minutes. Here's a tutorial that creates such a [wrapper for the `isatty` and `ttyname` functions](http://jonisalonen.com/2012/calling-c-from-java-is-easy/).

Answer (score 0):

As you say, in Java7, the JVM supports it, so you have a guarantee that this can be done portably in all OSs (because the JVM implementation takes care of it). Under Java7, you'd have to use a native library *per OS* you want to support. This is potentially even dirtier than executing `chmod`

Comment: So, what is the answer? No, you can't do it?

Comment: @DanielPeñalba right. To the best of my knowledge, pre-Java7, your best option is executing `chmod` if you are in linux. But wait a bit, other people might know better!