# How to know the Octal Permission of a file

Tags: java, linux, unix, stat

In my Java application , I am running following command to get the Octal permission and file name.

```
stat -c "%a %n" <file name>
```

This command works on Linux but the Solaris version I have doesnt have stat command supported.

How can I achieve this with a command which works on both Linux and Solaris
There are some options with perl stat but unfortunately I cant use perl.

Comment: Also see [How to manage linux file permissions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15568629/608639). Asking for a `stat` command replacement on Solaris is mostly off-topic for Stack Overflow. You might want to ask for a Posix command replacement at [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve same thing using **find** command

```
find <file name> -printf "%m %f"

find <directory name> -maxdepth 0 -printf "%m %f"
```

Example:

```
find /etc/passwd -printf "%m %f"

find /etc -maxdepth 0 -printf "%m %f"
```